# What happens when my proposal gets launched

Tags: discussion, site-proposal

I would like to know what exactly happens if my proposal gets launched. How would I contribute to the site? Does it make me a moderator or do I communicate with stack exchange admins? I would like a detailed walkthrough to what happens when someone owns a launched proposal.

Comment: Simple answer is you are really no different than any other contributor.  It's not really your site and you aren't given special privileges

Comment: Note that you don't even have automatic commit - many times the users who started the proposal are not committed to it when it reach the Commitment phase.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Oh my. Thanks for the tip. I will bear that in mind

Comment: Sure, so two more are coming your way! :) 1 - keep in mind you have one year for each phase: after one year, if the proposal fails to reach the next phase, it's auto closed. 2 - I took a glimpse on your proposal and looks like it's already part of  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/ - don't think there's need for whole new site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are just a normal user like any others. Okay, you had a good idea and the community supported your proposal, but that doesn't make the community yours.

If you are a active member during all phases of the proposal, you might be picked as a moderator through the election phase. If not, you just have to earn your moderation privileges like any others.

And sorry, you won't get a t-shirt, nor special access to the SE team.

Comment: Ok, thanks. And what if I want to change the site title image and icon? What do I do then?

Comment: You can't. SE is the only who can.

Comment: So I just mail them and make a request?

Comment: Raise it on the appropriate meta site. Logo and styling will be added when the site goes public.

Comment: Logos and themes are added when the site *graduates*, which takes years, and is done by the SE team's own designers (with community input).